# TreePath to java.io.File

Tags: java, file, path, jtree

Is there any easy way of getting a `File` (or `java.nio.file.Path`, for that matter) from a `TreePath`?

For example, you have a `JTree` like this:

```
Green
|---Blue
|---Red
|---Yellow
    |---Purple.jpg
    |---Brown.jpg
    |---Black.jpg
```

If you have a `TreePath` going to `Black.jpg`, is there a way to get a `File` (or `Path`) with path `Green\Yellow\Black.jpg`?

I can do it the long way, by taking parents/children one by one and constructing the path bit by bit, but I was hoping there might be a more elegant way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this pretty simply with a short regex and the `toString` method, heres a quick example:

```
TreePath tp = new TreePath(new String[] {"tmp", "foo", "bar"});
String path = tp.toString().replaceAll("\\]| |\\[|", "").replaceAll(",", File.separator);
File f = new File(path);
// path is now tmp\foo\bar on Windows and tmp/foo/bar on unix
```

**EDIT: Explanation**

1. `tp.toString()` - this calls the native to string method of an array, since that is the way TreePaths are represented under the covers. ***returns***: `[tmp, foo, bar]`
2. `replaceAll("\\]| |\\[|", "")` - this uses a simple regular expression to replace the characters `[` and `]` and also removes empty spaces. The character `|` means *or* in JAVA's flavor of RegEx, so this means "*if we encounter a left bracket, right bracket or empty space, replace it the empty string*." ***returns***: `tmp,foo,bar`
3. `.replaceAll(",", File.separator)` - the final step, this replaces commas with the native file path separator. ***returns***: `tmp/foo/bar or tmp\foobar`

Comment: Mind explaining to me what `"\\]| |\\[|"` exatly means? I've seen it before, but I never knew what it ment...

Comment: Just a regex, updated the question with explanation.

Answer (score 4):

I think your stuck with making your own method.

```
public static String createFilePath(TreePath treePath) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Object[] nodes = treePath.getPath();
    for(int i=0;i<nodes.length;i++) {
        sb.append(File.separatorChar).append(nodes[i].toString()); 
    } 
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I tried both of your solutions, Josiah's and ug_'s. This one worked for me. Thank you.