# Java File.isFile() returns false, but it is a file

Tags: java, file, nio

File is not read only as you can see from the screen shot below. But for some reasons file.isFile() is being returned as false. Below is my code:

```
TreePath selectedTreePath = tree.getPathForLocation(me.getX(), me.getY());
DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (selectedTreePath.getLastPathComponent());
File files = new File(node.getUserObject().toString());
File file = new File(node.getUserObject().toString());
Path path2 = Paths.get(node.getUserObject().toString());
System.out.println("path2.toAbsolutePath(): " + path2.toAbsolutePath());
System.out.println("path2.toFile().isFile(): " + path2.toFile().isFile());
```

What would be my work around?

Edit: So I think my first two lines of code is wrong? TreePath and DefaultMutableTreeNode. I am getting the path of the file incorrectly?
[image]
[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like it's a file to me, you're missing the \src.

Comment: You're right, I am missing /src. Why's that?

Answer (score -2):

Figured out the problem. I was doing funcky stuff with

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (selectedTreePath.getLastPathComponent());
```

Used the below code:

```
public static String createFilePath(TreePath treePath) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Object[] nodes = treePath.getPath();
    for(int i=0;i<nodes.length;i++) {
        sb.append(File.separatorChar).append(nodes[i].toString()); 
    } 
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20364909/1275777

Oh and it would be nice if you guys explained why you're marking it down.