# I am trying to get the path of folder on treeselectionlistner . Can anyone help me

Tags: java, jtree

I am trying to get the path of folder on treeselectionlistner . Can anyone help me . I want exact path of folder i am selection in JTree .

//Class 1

public class FileBrowser implements Runnable {

```
private DefaultMutableTreeNode root;

private DefaultTreeModel treeModel;

private JTree tree;

@Override
public void run() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("File Browser");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    File fileRoot = new File("C:\\JDeveloper\\Testing");
    root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new FileNodes(fileRoot));
    treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);

    tree = new JTree(treeModel);
    tree.setCellRenderer(new DefaultTreeCellRenderer() {
        private Icon loadIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
        private Icon saveIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");
        @Override
        public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent( JTree tree,
                                                       Object value,
                                                       boolean bSelected,
                                                       boolean bExpanded,
                                                       boolean bLeaf,
                                                       int iRow,
                                                       boolean bHasFocus ) {
            Component c = super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value,
                    bSelected, bExpanded, false, iRow, bHasFocus);

            return c;
        }
    });
    tree.setShowsRootHandles(true);
    tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {
         public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
           DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e
               .getPath().getLastPathComponent();
           System.out.println("You selected " +node);
         }
       });
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);

    frame.add(scrollPane);
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setSize(640, 480);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    CreateChildNode ccn = new CreateChildNode(fileRoot, root);
    new Thread(ccn).start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new FileBrowser());
}
```

}

class CreateChildNode implements Runnable {

```
private DefaultMutableTreeNode root;

private File currentFile;

public CreateChildNode(File currentFile, DefaultMutableTreeNode root) {
    this.currentFile = currentFile;
    this.root = root;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    createChildren(currentFile, root);
}

private void createChildren(File currentFile, DefaultMutableTreeNode node)
{
    File[] files = currentFile.listFiles();
    if ( files != null )
    {
        for( File file : files )
        {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode( new FileNodes( file ) );
            if( file.isDirectory() )
            {
                node.add( childNode );
                createChildren( file, childNode );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

class FileNodes {

```
private File file;

public FileNodes(File file) {
    this.file = file;
}
public File getFile() {
    return file;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String name = file.getName();
    if (name.equals("")) {
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    } else {
        return name;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Duplicated question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38607969/i-am-trying-to-get-the-path-of-folder-on-treeselectionlistner/38610380#38610380

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update the `TreeSelectionListener` `valueChanged()` method as follows

```
tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e.getPath().getLastPathComponent();
        FileNodes fileNode = (FileNodes)node.getUserObject();
        System.out.println("You selected " + fileNode.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot bro once agin.

Comment: OP has taken answer from here and claimed as own on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38607969/i-am-trying-to-get-the-path-of-folder-on-treeselectionlistner/38610380#38610380

Answer (score 0):

change

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e
           .getPath().getLastPathComponent();
```

to

```
TreePath node = (TreePath) e
           .getPath();
```

Currently you are telling it to only give you the end of the path, I presume you want the whole thing.

To get the file it refers to, use this code:

```
String path = node.toString().replaceAll("\\]| |\\[|", "").replaceAll(",", File.separator);
File f = new File(path);
```

from this answer: [TreePath to java.io.File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364571/treepath-to-java-io-file)

Comment: What error? I can't help if I don't know the problem. Use the debug tools in whatever IDE you are using and figure that out first

Comment: This is because in your code you are casting it to a DefualtTreeModel.... I have updated my answer to show what you should do. If you want a oofile reference to the file the TreePath points to, I have included that t

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:762)
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:906)

Comment: public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
                 TreePath tp = new TreePath(new String[] {"tmp", "foo", "bar"});
     String path = tp.toString().replaceAll("\\]| |\\[|", "").replaceAll(",", File.separator);
                 File f = new File(path);
//                 TreePath path = e.getPath();
//                 DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e
//                            .getPath().getLastPathComponent();
               System.out.println("You selected " +f.getAbsolutePath());
             }
           });